# Why is my function not invoking when the condition is satified?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, date

I'm trying to invoke a function on a specific date and time, but unfortunately the function is not getting invoked when I expect. I am expecting to invoke `shuffleResources()` on Monday at 8:00AM.

Why is my code below not doing that?

```
const RequestManagement = (items) => {
    //state initialization  
    var date = new Date();
    const Monday = date.getDay();
    const Min = date.getMinutes();   


    if(Monday === 1 && Minute === 03){
    console.log("It Enters Inside");
    shuffleResource(); 
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();     

    }, []);
    const loadData = () => {
        // functionality- getting backend data here
    };

    const moveItem = async (from, to) => {
        // remove `from` item and store it
        var f = shuffle.splice(from, 1)[0];
        // insert stored item into position `to`
        shuffle.splice(to, 0, f);
        setCharacters(shuffle[0].items);
        setCharacters1(shuffle[1].items);
        setCharacters2(shuffle[2].items);
        setCharacters3(shuffle[3].items);

        await shuffleRsrc(shuffle).then((data) => {
            if (data.success === true) {
                console.log("successfull!");
            } else {
                console.log("not successful...");
            }
        })
    }

    const shuffleResources = () => {
        console.log('This will run every second!');
        moveItem(0, 4);
    }
    return ();
}
```

Comment: *"Expecting to invoke shuffleResources() when its Monday and time 8.00AM."* That's not what your condition is checking. Your condition is checking whether it's monday (because the `getDay()` part being `1` is correct) and it's the fourth minute of **any** hour (`Minute === 03`). (Side note: Don't write integers with leading zeroes like that, just write `3`, not `03` ([why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal)). [Exception: It's okay when writing a fractional number that only has a `0` before the `.`, like `0.1`.])

Comment: (Also, one part of your code is using `shuffleResource` [without an `s`] and another is using `shuffleResources` [with an `s`]).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agree. For example I just added Minute as 03, but for every Monday and 8AM that function needs to be called.

Comment: its ShuffleResources() only. Missed 's' while posting this as question over here

Answer (score 0):

```
const date= new Date();
const day = date.getDay();
const time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
if(day===1 && time === "08:00:00"){
    //invokes function
}
```

Comment: no luck. same issue